# How do I set the behavior for an inflated view?

Tags: android, android-activity, behavior, viewstub

I have an audio player toolbar activity that has a corresponding layout file.

I need this player to show up at the bottom of another activity. I use a ViewStub and inflate the audio toolbar's layout file in the stub.

How do I access the buttons, etc on this inflated view and how do I set their behavior?

The docs on ViewStub did not mention anything about this (or maybe I totally overlooked something).

I may be doing something fundamentally wrong here so I would appreciate any help I can get :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've inflated a view, you call findViewById on the view with the ID.  e.g.

```
View v = ...;
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

if in your xml you had a declaration of a TextView with id "@+id/textview"

Comment: Thanks :) I did not know that it worked that way too. I thought that you can only do that if the view is declared in that activity's XML